QField V. 3.4.0 - Ebo - Geoprocessing toolbox
QField V. 3.4.0 Ebo release says that one of the changes is

A nifty processing toolbox has been added into QField, with countless algorithms available to edit features and geometries while in the field

However, I cannot find it when I open QGIS either using my Android Mobile or through the Windows app.
Currently, I'm using V. 3.4.2.
Does anybody know what's going on?

Do you mean QField when you say QGIS in the However sentence?

You can access it from the options when viewing one or more features as a list.
First, select one or more features from the same layer - tap on a feature on the canvas to identify it, which brings up the features list; then select it (green checkbox in list view). Two ways to do it are to either long press the feature in the list, or tap the three dots on the top right of the list and select Toggle Feature Selection, then select the checkbox that appears next to the feature in the list. You can then select other features in the same layer by tapping on them on the canvas.
Then, with at least one of the features selected, tap the three-dot icon on the top left of the features list. You will see Process Select Features as the bottom most option.

Once selected, switch to the All Algorithms tab to see all available processing tools - they will differ based on the geometry type. I believe the only ones available are those that can use the modify in-place function in QGIS; no new layers are generated (so for example you can't generate a buffer from a point, but you can apply a buffer to a polygon - it will modify the feature but not create a new layer or feature).
The screenshot below shows some of the options for a polygon:

